# geometric algebra, complex vector space, hyperplane reflection

Tags: computational-geometry

in relation to some audio processing I would like do a hyperplane reflection in a complex vector space using clifford geometric algebra. I have been looking on the web for a few weeks but have not really found an answer. For a longer time I have used hyperplane reflections in n-dimensional real vector spaces done with geometric algebra, (every basis element : e1, e2, ...en squares to +1). Vector 'a' is normalized to length 1. Vector 'x' reflected in a hyperplane orthogonal to vector 'a' can be computed : x -> -axa. I have no problems here, I have thoroughly tested and used my functions. I am trying to write a similar function for vectors 'a' and 'x' both being complex of dimension n. My guess is x -> -ax(a_conjugate). ||a|| = 1. But this is not right / it does not work. Any hints towards a formula or good sources on the subject are most welcome. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the operation applied to `a`, `x`, and `a_conjugate`? There is no geometric product that corresponds to the complex norm, as it is not a quadratic form and doesn't produce a Clifford algebra.

Comment: Yes -  the norm and how it generates the Clifford algebra is probably the first thing I should try to understand to get further with this .. For x->-ax(a^-1) I just tried to put complex numbers in the place of real numbers and with a_conjugate being a vector with complex entries, complex conjugate to 'a'.  And then replace all multiplications with complex number multiplications . And indeed use the complex norm ||x||^2 = x*x_conjugate at the same time as the geometric product. But yes, it is obviously an over simplification, which does not lead anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps http://versor.mat.ucsb.edu/?